# Why do I need for() to make setInterval work?

Tags: javascript

I am making an animation at the end of a game. I have this code pieced together from various googles.

```
function showSpider(){
    for (var i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        var theInterval=setInterval(function() { 
            newX=newX+1;
            if (newX>100){
                newX=100; 
                clearInterval(theInterval);
                document.getElementById('speak').style.visibility="visible";  
            }
            document.getElementById('spideranim').style.webkitTransform = "translate3d        (250px, "+newX+"px,0px)"; 
            document.getElementById('spideranim').style.visibility="visible";  
        }, 100); 
    }
    var temp=(Math.ceil((fliesShown/keysHit)*100));
    document.getElementById("speak").value="You got "+temp+" percent.";     
}
```

The problem is it works. I tried to take out the for statement as it should not be necessary for the interval. Then the spider animation doesn't show up. No errors presented.

Why can't I take it out?

I also tried just setInterval with this code:

```
function showSpider() {
    theInterval=setInterval("wasteTime()",1000);
    var temp=(Math.ceil((fliesShown/keysHit)*100));
    document.getElementById("speak").value="You got "+temp+" percent accuracy.";        
}

function wasteTime(){   
    newX=newX+1;
    //alert("newX"+newX);
    //alert(document.getElementById('spideranim').style.webkitTransform);
    //alert(document.getElementById('spideranim').style.visiblity);
    if (newX>100){
        newX=100; 
        clearInterval(theInterval);
        document.getElementById('speak').style.visibility="visible";  
    }
    document.getElementById('spideranim').style.webkitTransform = "translate3d    (250px, "+newX+"px,0px)"; 
    document.getElementById('spideranim').style.visibility="visible"; 
}
```

This does not work. Why does it not work?

Comment: The version with the for loop is only calling `clearInterval()` on the last timer that was started, the rest of the animations keep running.

Comment: In your second block of code, are you declaring `theInterval` in a parent scope?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/DCFF5/

Answer (score 1):

- Short answer:

newX never becomes > 100 because `newX=newX+1;` isn't executed.

- Long answer:

Needs some more context.. cant tell whats going on without other code - but without the *for* loop, newX never becomes greater than 100 because `newX=newX+1;` isn't executed.

Thus, newX would just stay whatever value it was before the loop (eg: `newX=40`). As a result, `document.getElementById('speak').style.visibility="visible";` is never executed (im blindly assuming thats a win message of sorts)

Comment: Jsfiddle from wmfairuz showed the answer and now it works. Thanks

Comment: hover cursor over comment, and a "up arrow" will appear to the left of the comment :)

Comment: So, sorry to bother people here. I am trying to figure out why I was downvoted. Evidently "Stack Exchange web sites are question and answer sites, not help forums. This implies that all posts are expected to have some value for later visitors too. To enforce that, and to prevent help vampires making the answerers turn away from the communities, low-quality questions and answers are blocked. " I guess I will look for the forums that will help me learn enough to be of help to others without bashing me in that process.

Comment: Some people come here, and ask for an answer without providing some evidence of an effort made. This gives the impression that theyre just looking for a college assignment solution, and not actually willing to learn more about the programming language. Your large amounts of code (supplied in the question) gived such an impression, but it was not the case - you were looking for an answer to something you already tried finding out, and are willing to understand why it didn't work. Thats why it was downvoted (then again, 2 points isnt much lol) :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I do want to learn how to do it better.  I got the impression I was not allowed to ask if I couldn't answer questions too.  I don't know enough to help anyone yet.  The response "Look at this jsfiddle.net/DCFF5 – wmfairuz " will help anyone else looking at the interval so I guess it turns out good in the end.